# Text does not appear on the same page as the image

Tags: floats

My problem here is that the first figure works just fine. I can add text to the page where the first figure lies, text can be placed before or after the figure and appears where it should be. However, the second figure is forced into its own page. No text can be added after the figure, it is instead evacuated to the page where the first figure lies, and is placed after that figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\tolerance

 \begin{document}

\section{section X}
 some text which appears where it should be
\begin{figure}[h]
\hspace*{-4.5cm}
\centering
 %figure content
\end{figure}
 some more text which appears where it should be, lets call this place ***
 %problems start here
\begin{figure}[h]
\hspace{-4.5cm}
\centering
  %content of the second figure, identical in size to the first one
\end{figure}
 text here is evacuated to ***
 
\end{document}
```

I've tried changing [h] to different settings, Floatbarriers, making the figures smaller etc.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz is asking you to make a MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: why load inputenc three times? (It is not needed at all). You can include an image with `\includegraphics`.  The _only_ reason to wrap that in a `figure` enviroment is to allow the figure to be moved to help with page breaking so what you describe is the expected behaviour.

Comment: If you really use `figure` without `\caption`, why are you using `figure`? If the figure should not float, just put it into your code without `figure` environment. Alternatively you also could use a `minipage`, maybe in combination with a `flushleft` or `center` environment. But, if LaTeX places a figure not *here*, it usually does not fit. But I do not know, if this is the case, because your code does not work, nor does it show the issue.

Comment: Oh, maybe it shows the issue, if we make the example working, But note also, that *here* floats in the middle of a paragraph always float to a position after the current line. So text after the float can always be printed before the float, if the paragraph break moves it into the current line.